# Cancel UIScrollView bounce animation after didEndDragging?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a horizontal `UIScrollView`. I want to implement a custom animation instead of the default bounce, where I pull all the way past the right edge of the scroll view's content size, the scroll view fly back to *(0, 0)* content offset after releasing finger.

Is there a way to cancel the bounce animation, keep the content offset from resetting, and then perform my animation?

I found a solution to this problem. Just use the `UIScrollView` delegate method:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset
```

Answer (score 0):

Thinking extemporaneously, without testing in code, grab the `contentOffset`, then set it back with [`setContentOffset:... animated:NO`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIScrollView/setContentOffset%3aanimated%3a). That should cancel the ongoing animation and transition instantly to the position given. Since the position given is the current position, it should just cancel the animation.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have tried this. But it can't overrides the bounce animation.

Comment: Avoiding the issue instead, have you tried setting `bounces` to `NO` and therefore having no animation to cancel? Failing that, you could try `removeAllAnimations` on the layer. Do either of those ideas work?